# Arduino connection confirmation

Tags: arduino-uno, relay

I am using Arduino Uno. I want to control my room lamp both manually and over the network, so when I switch off my lamp manually, how do I get acknowledgement over the network that lamp is off ?

Comment: Disconnect the switch from the lamp and instead connect it to a digital pin on the Arduino. Have the Arduino toggle the lamp when the switch changes position.

Comment: Or attach a lightsensor to see if the bulb is on.

Comment: @Gerben not nice.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). What do you mean by "manually"? What do you mean by "acknowledgement over the network"? I don't know why the above comments have been reported to the moderators.

Comment: @PhillyNJ could you explain what you mean by `not nice`? Do you mean it's unsafe to do so?

Comment: @Gerben - My mistake.- I read it wrong. Sorry